# Nested dictionary behavior

Tags: python

I am trying to learn how to manipulate data in python.
I have the following data in a txt file

```
{"summonerId":000000,"games":[{"gameId":111111,"invalid":false,"gameMode":"CLASSIC","gameType":"MATCHED_GAME","subType":"NORMAL","mapId":11,"teamId":200,"championId":89,"spell1":3,"spell2":4,"level":30,"ipEarned":237,"createDate":1443314494341,"fellowPlayers":[{"summonerId":46350758,"teamId":100,"championId":157}],"stats":{"level":15,"goldEarned":10173,"numDeaths":5,"minionsKilled":48,"championsKilled":1,"goldSpent":9205,"totalDamageDealt":48752,"totalDamageTaken":23464,"team":200,"win":true,"largestMultiKill":1,"physicalDamageDealtPlayer":9064,"magicDamageDealtPlayer":35714,"physicalDamageTaken":18944,"magicDamageTaken":4005,"timePlayed":1831,"totalHeal":4129,"totalUnitsHealed":5,"assists":24,"item0":3401,"item1":2049,"item2":3117,"item3":3068,"item4":3075,"item5":1028,"item6":3340,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":9062,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":3348,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":12411,"trueDamageDealtPlayer":3974,"trueDamageTaken":514,"wardKilled":1,"wardPlaced":16,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":104,"playerRole":2,"playerPosition":4}]}
```

My end goal is to be able to display a specific piece of information from the "stats" dictionary.

When I run the following code

```
import json
matches = open('testdata.txt', 'r')
output = matches.read()
data=json.loads(output)
display = data["games"]
print("Info: " + str(display))
```

The output is everything that corresponds to the "games" key as I would expect.

When I try

```
import json
matches = open('testdata.txt', 'r')
output = matches.read()
data=json.loads(output)
display = data["games"]["stats"]
print("Info: " + str(display))
```

I receive: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

I'm not really sure how to proceed given that the key is clearly a string and not an integer...

Comment: The JSON sample you shared is invalid; the `000000` value is not a valid JSON number, and there appears to be a `}` missing. Since your code obviously managed to load the data (your first sample code works) your *real* file contains something different.

Comment: Yes! I changed the id value out of respect for other's privacy. Interesting about the missing } though, I will look into it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `data["games"]` value is a *list*; each element in that list is a dictionary, and it is those dictionaries in the list that (may) have the `'stats'` key. A list can contain 0 or more elements; in this specific case there is just 1 but there could be more or none.

Loop over the list of dictionaries, or pick a specific dictionary from the list with indexing. Since there is only one in *your specific example*, you could just index that 1 element with the `0` index:

```
display = data["games"][0]["stats"]
```